# Motion blur on texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blur

Is it possible to have motion blur on moving texture via variable mapping location coordinates ? I am using cycles.

[image: mapping]

I am trying to have ground animated with motion blur, but don't want to change position or size of plane.

[image: animation]

([http://i.imgur.com/b752zJX.gif](https://i.imgur.com/b752zJX.gif) for animation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Motion blur will not work** because the object doesn't move in the scene. What you need to do is to **blur the texture** in the nodes. For it there is nice node group named ImageBlur from the [b°wide NodePack](https://bwide.wordpress.com/node-groups/bwide-nodepack-for-blender/). This node will blur the image in all directions, put it between *Tex. Coords.* and *Image Texture* nodes. You can **control the amount of blur**:

[image]

To blur only in one direction we need to adjust the *ImageBlur* group node. Add those *Separate RGB*, *Add* and *Combine RGB* nodes and change marked values:

[image]

Now you have blur only in one direction:

[image]

If you also plug in 2 *Mapping* nodes with opposite values for rotation in Z you can change the blur angle:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this particular case might be using two different textures, the clean one you have, and another one previously blurred in Photoshop, GIMP or any other software.

Then, in the material nodes, mix the two textures with a regular Mix Node and animate the Factor between 0 and 1 when your mapping starts or ends its movement.

You may animate it manually, unless some math guru gives you a magic Driver setup for this.

Note that if you simply blur your current texture, it's not going to be seamless. First make a composition of 3 tiles, apply the directional blur to it and then cut the middle tile.

Comment: This is fine if the blur amount is constant (and much more efficient than the other answer which uses a noise texture to 'blur' the vectors), but if you have to show the increase/decrease of speed, a simple fade between the blurred and un-blurred texture will look bad.

Comment: You're right. If the acceleration were fast, it could be fine. Maybe another intermediate texture could improve the result.

Comment: Yep, you would need to have a texture for every frame, which you could easily pump out of blender's compositor.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about fading between 3 different textures actually. It need to be tested, but it might work.

Comment: Meant for every frame of the transition (not the whole animation), but think we're thinking the same thing basically :)