# How to create a procedural chevron like texture/material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm playing around with nodes within cycles and I'd love to create a chevron like texture like the image below. Anyone an idea how to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: How's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDwU.png)?

Comment: Accidentaly made this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XKe.jpg it's pretty I don't want to delete it :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Start with **Wave** procedural texture and create tiling in X axis with [Repeating patterns on procedural textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26703/7777). After that clamp the values into stripes with a *ColorRamp node* set to constant:

[image]

[image]
 <sub>(^*click to enlarge*)</sub>

You can adjust the stripes with the *ColorRamp node*:

[image]

For mapping procedural textures onto spherical objects there has to be additional transforming of mapping coordinates:

For **procedural cylindrical projection** this node group:

[image]

[image]

And for **procedural spherical projection** this node group:

[image]

[image]

Using the spherical projection with the tiled chevron procedural texture:

[image]

Here we also added an extra *Mapping node* to control stretching of the texture around the surface.

Download the .blend file with append-able node groups here:

[image]

On the egg shape cylindrical projection looks the best:

[image]

Comment: Jaroslav, do you have a channel in Youtube?

Comment: @RitaGeraghty I do, but with no 3D content or tutorials.