# Rotationally stretch or compress 3D texture around Z axis

Tags: procedural, scale, texture-coordinates, distort

I want to distort a 3D texture around the Z axis in Cycles.
I found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material/45169#45169) that you can convert cartesian texture coortinates to polar coordinates but the problem is that you end up with a projected 2D texture. I want to preserve all the 3 dimensions and stretch or squash the texture around the Z axis to get a behavior like this :

[image]

...but with 3D texture coordinates.

Can we achieve that with Cycles nodes ?

Comment: you want to scale a texture around the Z axis, or do you want to create the effect shown on the bottom image, or is the texture intended to control the distortion of the objects?

Comment: I want to scale the texture around the Z axis which would give the effect on the bottom image except not with meshes but instead a 3D texture (like noise or voronoi). So if I were to use volume scattering I would get the same behavior. Of course there would be a half plane in which the texture would disappear as I would scale it down which would create a seam, just like for the Cartesian to Polar coordinates conversion.

Comment: I swear I did this by accident yesterday answering another question.
Trying to find it.

Comment: Please find it back !

Comment: Sorry, not sure what did it, I know I was messing with the scale, mapping node, separating the XYZ and some math nodes in between, I saw that effect and tought that it looked neat, and then went on because what I was lookign for had nothing to do with that.

Also it probably wasn't a clean answer either, because I suspect the real answer is probably much more complex, Im going to give it a whirl, but I think this might be above my possibilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61465/discussion-between-firewill-and-chameleonscales).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.
The idea is to use a gradient node in radial mode and plug it to the angle of a rotation node (just like a Mapping node but with an input socket for the rotation). Since such a node doesn't exist in Blender we make it with math nodes.

First the rotation node itself (it's a node group) :

[image: Blender rotation node group]

then the general setup (the green node is the rotation we made above and the yellow node is the one to animate (the second value in the Multiply node) :

[image: distort 3D texture around Z axis node setup]

Result :

[image: distort 3D texture around Z axis]

Here is the file :
[image]

Comment: Why put in an answer that says "I found a solution and I am currently making this reply that I will edit..."? Just write your answer, then post it.

Comment: no kidding it was simple >.< great solution, looks really fun!

Answer (score 2):

[image: radial coordinates]
Just for illustration of what I PM earlier..

Comment: this solution is also great, tough I don't understand the math behind it, super elegant!

Comment: yes but the result is not as clean towards the center (the texture converges to it). You can see it when looking from the top.