# How do I make a herringbone pattern?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to create a herringbone pattern that will wrap around a cylinder. I'm assuming that there's a way to do this using the brick texture node but I can't work out how to alternate and/or manipulate the rotation of bricks within the pattern itself?

Edit: The pattern is not the same as that than in the answer that I'm being told this is a duplicate of - that's not even close to the pattern I'm looking for. I'm looking for a herringbone pattern as in the example below, not just simple zig zags. Any actual help greatly appreciated!

[image: Something like this]

Comment: It's almost the same, you just start with s sheared brick texture.

Comment: Not sure how to apply that example to my above question? Not looking to make alternating waves, looking to make the pattern almost exactly as above in the reference.

Comment: You apply the example by starting with sheared brick texture, the rest is the same. You shear the brick texture by adding together x and y mapping vectors and plugging that into y mapping texture input.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcIu2hIO4Og

Comment: It's called a chevron pattern, this post goes into more detail with a great solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material

Comment: Does the duplicate answer not match due to the solid colours? Do you need the lines as in your original image?

Comment: Yes - I'm not looking to made zigzags as in the duplicate answer, I'm looking to make the pattern as in the example above, with the lines in between. Making alternating stripes is not what I'm looking to do - I want to know how to make the lines appear in between, that is the most important part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a texture map instead of a procedural map.

I made a seamless tile using your image.

You can play the dimensions using a mapping node.

See the image below:
[image]

Comment: cannot see why this was down voted twice without any comments. It certainly is not ideal to use a bitmap with fixed pixels but it is a route to completing what the poster wanted.