# V shaped gradient texture - Car Livery

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am working on a livery of F1 car (it's my first project after tutorials) and want to achieve a V-shaped car livery like on this photo:
[image: Mclaren]

I created a gradient texture with texture coordinate on an empty, like the guy in this video:
[YouTube](https://youtu.be/Enc4Gk_PmC8?t=157) and it looks like below. The empty allows me to rotate and scale the gradient texture. I thought that since there is a Mirror modifier on the body, the shader would also be mirrored, but it's not the case. I want to mirror it, like on the screen from the video.

I tried moving, rotating and scaling the empty, but it didn't work :(
[image: My work]

Gradient I want to achieve:
[image: Video]

Comment: Hi and welcome! I'd suggest to use an *image texture* instead, I personally do not see any reason why this has to be a procedural shader. BTW: Recommend to take the [tour] to learn about how this site works. Good luck!

Comment: Related: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Comment: Thank you,  this actually may be the easiest solution! But what if I wanted to keep it procedural, just for the future?

Comment: Digital images won't go away in the near future, bullet proof since early 1960s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image :D

Comment: Related: [how to create a procedural chevron like thexture material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material)

Comment: @susu Thank you! I didn't know the word "chevron" so i couldn't search for it... :D

Answer (score 6):

You were so nearly there... :D

At the risk of starting a game of Node Golf, if the question is: ['How do I make a procedural chevron?'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material) ...then a minimal answer could be something like this, mirroring in X by using its *Absolute* value:

[image]

This assumes the origin of your model is on its mirror axis. The *Map Range* 'From' figures would depend on the size of your object. Both of those conditions are tweakable.

The texture is in XY, and can be projected through any model:

[image]

@brockmann: to get a rounding at the tip pf the chevron without getting too complicated, you could forget the *Absolute*, and select ranges from `y + sqrt((x^2) +n)`. Here illustrated with `n=0.005`, `n=0.001`, and `n=0`, which returns us to the un-rounded chevron.

[image]

Blurring could be achieved by chnging the Color Ramp from 'Constant', and putting in gradients from red to white, and/or, muddling the whole texture space with some noise.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! ![It worked](https://ibb.co/TTX4CfS).

Comment: In order to make it *less* perfect (for realism), do you see any chance to round up the corners and blur the lines it a tiny bit? BTW: Nice answer!

Comment: @brockmann yes, but it costs a square root!  >8/

Comment: @susu Good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. You may need to adjust the values to fit the size of your object, but the idea is the same - to use wave textures, scaled down so they're only one or 2 stripes, then adding them together on 45 degree angles so they cross in the center of the object. That in mind, using object texture coordinates is a good place to start:

[image: Car1]

As you can see from the next 2 images, one Wave texture alone doesn't have both the "chevrons" pointing in the desired directions at the same time, so the solution is to use the rotation of mapping nodes to make one going each way, and then splitting their presentation with a Gradient Texture. I also took this opportunity to make the "back" chevron thicker than the front using the ColorRamp:

[image: Car2]

[image: Car3]

Here is the gradient. I separated the X and used a ColorRamp set to *constant* to ensure an even split, then I used this as a mix factor between the two directions:

[image: Car4]

I then used this new formed texture as a mix factor between white and red:

[image: Car5]

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you! Even if i end up using a texture image, I will certainly try to do it your way, just to try it and learn. Thank you so much!