# Blender pattern query

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

I am looking to create a zig zag pattern across the surface of a sphere with horizontal lines going across the thicker zigzag [image]like the attached picture in blender on a sphere. Can anyone tell me what the texture nodes would be to create this? Thanks very much

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material

Comment: Thank you Duarte, I wondered if there is a way to create the lines across the zigzags like the image above? Thanks