# How would you create Pixel Art in blender without using a Shader?

Tags: texturing, objects, workflow

How would you create pixel art like this https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/B1inDVWIEAAm2XK.mp4 in Blender?
I understand Sean Young creates the original sprites in Photoshop and imports them, but how does he color them? Does he use planes as the structure of his sprites? It's just so vague to me, and I haven't found any sources online to how he created this.

Comment: I guess the author uses a few planes to hold RGBA images. It is unlikely that one would set colors for every quad (px).

Comment: Well, he probably just uses square plane faces, and then adds a texture on the planes.

Comment: I think that @LeonCheung is right. You can clearly see it in one of his tweet: https://twitter.com/SeanYoungSG/status/689418972995817473

Comment: Could you please explain your question? The title says you want to do this without creating a shader, but that is the best method. Do you want to know "how he created this", or "How would you create Pixel Art in blender without using a Shader"?

Comment: Sorry; I should evaluate what i said. Uncle Snail, I was curious as to how he did this like you said. It's just after researching for hours all i found was ways to create pixel art using Shaders. To finalize, my question is "How did he create this"

Comment: you can use nodes to pixelate your texture.
Here in the forum a guy posted a nice setup http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles And here it was used to create a pixelated minecraft block. In this video you can see, how to paint your texture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZPtl1F1N-0 So for your example - simple create a plane mesh, that will look like your guy, unwrap it, paint it and pixelate it with the nodes :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GUYS I FINALLY WORKED IT OUT :D**

After literally asking him online  through social media; he answered! Credits to [Leon Cheung](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/696/leon-cheung) and [Carlo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15140/carlo) for being correct on the whole process. He uses the Import > Image to Plane feature addon within Blender. Furthermore, he stated that instead of creating armatures and a rig for his assets, he uses plane animation to move each plane.

I'm really grateful to all the responses i received within the time of this post. Hope this finally cleared it all up <3

Here's something I created with the knowledge i gained:
[image: Pixel man creation <3]

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an alpha layer in photoshop and then set the opacity to 0 of the background in blender. You can do it with a single square plane.

Answer (score 0):

I have coloured a simple photo in the compositor but you could do this as a post process for renders.

1. find edges with a Filter>Sobol node
2. apply a color curve to enhance edges (and reverse or correct color- notice direction of curve slope)
3. Use 2 Transform nodes (set to interpolate>Nearest) between a Pixelate node. Use a Input Value node and modify it with 2 math nodes a/Multiply 0.1 b/Divide 10.0
4. Simply mix the results to achieve a coloured outline 8 bit effect.

[image]