# Blocky noise texture in blender

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

How do I go about creating a blocky noise texture similar to the one attached. This was done in After Effects using the Fractal Noise effect set to "Block".

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles) and [this article](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/white_noise.html) from the blender documentation came really close, but the blocks are still too even and all neatly aligned in columns and rows.

[image]

Comment: RGB mixing multiple brick textures with different parameters set to Multiply sort of does the trick. Though not sure if that is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with a mix of voronoi textures (with randomness = 0).
check this setup and result:

[image]