# Pixelating Grease Pencil (not using the pixelate effect)

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes, grease-pencil, pixel-art

Instead of this

https://gyazo.com/bed4b90049e403aa1a1074e8dff8682a

I want this (I used photoshop to pixelate for demostration)

https://gyazo.com/1b6eebc60183893a8d0e8a2ca0908d53

I've wanted to pixelate my grease pencil that it doesn't keep facing the camera in all directions like the pixelate effect does built-in blender. I wanna pixelate my strokes (including the fills) in a same plane just like how we pixelate a normal 2d picture portrayed in this [How to pixelate a texture in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles), but that solution doesn't seem to apply in grease pencil.

I've come up with different ideas to do it, like Animation nodes and script. I've thought of making a script/animation node structure that'll get the average/dominant color on each divisions of a bounding box to get the pixelated data and then create a grid mesh of it, but it doesn't seem to work/to be the optimal way because grease pencil has depth. Is there other way like converting the grease pencil into mesh then do pixelate like what was done in the link above, or is it a blender restriction?

I'd love to hear your thoughts and ideas!