# How could I shade a pixelated texture?

Tags: shaders

okay so you know in minecraft when you turn of smooth lighting and every block gets shaded a color each? I'm trying to do something similar with shader nodes.
This is as close as I've been able to come
[image: my attempt at per-pixel lighting]
here's the node tree
[image: the node tree]
as you can see there are individual pixels but many of them are partially shaded
so in summary, i want to shade the individual pixels of a pixel art texture and not the entire smooth surface. If anyone has a good idea or someone that has done something similar I would love you forever.

this question has been identified as a possible duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles) but as you can see, that is pretty much exactly what i tried. but it didn't work. the issue is definitley in the use of the diffuse bsdf but i do not know what could work as a substitute for lighting information

[image: the first image but there is a texture under the shading]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pixelate a texture in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles)