# How can I create a staggered, repeating procedural pattern?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I read ["How do I create repeating patterns in cycles with procedural textures?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures?rq=1) here on Blender Stack Exchange, and ["staggered texture mapping"](http://adaptivesamples.com/2014/06/16/staggered-texture-mapping/) on Greg Zaal's website.  I thought it seemed possible to combine the two ideas to have staggered procedural tiles, but can't seem to make it work.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: can you post an example of staggered procedural pattern

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are the nodes for creating staggered texture mapping for procedural textures.
[image: cycles nodes for the texture coordinates]
First the Y axis gets multiplied by the number of lines you want to have in the pattern (the *Lines* value node).  After adding `.5` that gets rounded creating stripes (along the X axis in this example).

- If you were to look at the output from that node at this point it would look all white, that is because the values start at 1 and increase by 1 with each stripe.

[image: section of the cycles nodes]

The next three nodes take the stripes, multiplies it by the reciprocal of the input value (lines), then by `0.5` to lower the values. Then the X axis is added in.
[image: section of the cycles nodes]
At this point there are only stripes, next the *Modulo* math node causes the texture coordinates to repeat.
All that was for the X axis.

The Y axis is simple, it is just the Modulo of the reciprocal of the *lines*.

With the nodes pictured at the top you can get a pattern like this.
[image: generated procedural pattern]

After adding the *Subtract* and *Absolute* nodes from [Jerryno's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26703/2217),  every other tile will be mirrored and you can get a pattern like this.
[image: generated procedural pattern]

This blend has the nodes packed in to a node group, which can easily be added to any project.

### [Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/198/)

As you can see, manipulating the texture coordinates of generated textures is quite powerful.

Comment: You are the king.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, but only on 2.8

https://gumroad.com/l/Brcks

you can append "br`ck" node tree then use br`ck_v1.1 node like this

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73275)

Comment: @Georges, thanks for correction.