# Texture for a fireplace

Tags: texturing

I`m trying to make this fireplace in blender and can˙t figure out how to make the texture in white. [image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which Render Engine do you use?

Comment: I use Cycles render

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the job for a Voronoi texture. While not exactly the same you can approximate that pattern relatively closely.

You can either apply it at material level, as a *Bump* map or as material based displacement, or you can use it as geometry level with a *Displacement Node*.

Last option will produce actual geometry but most likely require very high levels of subdivision and hence very dense geometry.

1. Shader Bump Map
   [image: Shader Bump Map]
2. Material Displacement
   [image]
3. Geometry displacement
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: That was also my first guess, but if you look closely, the pattern is repeatable and symmetrical.

Comment: True, that would probably require a seamless technique like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures), producing a dedicated  image based texture, or maybe through manually sculpting

Comment: I've managed to make it like so: https://imgur.com/f09EWjb just simple wire, 3x array, skin and sub-d. Should be better after baking seamles part of it and use as a texture.

Comment: Ah I see now, it actually does have a repeatable geometric pattern to it. That looks pretty good, sounds like a valid answer, you should definitely post it