Is there a way to make an animated procedural texture loop seamlessly?
After following some tutorials online I've made a basic texture from overlayed noises that scrolls up a shape on the Z axis, like fire.
I've noticed that the texture will go on forever, which would be fine if I were making an animation, but I was hoping for this to loop seamlessly, so that I could then somehow export it as a series of images for use in an old game (which is limited to flipbook style sprite sheets rather than fancy shaders etc.)
Is there some way to make Blender limit the generated texture so that it will loop how I wish it to? (while being able to specify the speed etc.)
And while not strictly Blender related - if not, is anyone aware of another program which can create procedural textures similar to Blender, that can be looped seamlessly and exported as frame-by-frame textures/sprite sheets?
Many thanks for any assistance!

May be relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195316/35559

In my example the noise texture gets duplicated (they have to be identical).
Noise A: its mapping Z loc is animated from 0 to 1.
Noise B: its mapping Z loc is animated from -1 to 0.
Mix factor is animated from 0 to 1.
All animations have to be interpolated in a linear way (select all on Dopesheet, right click > Interpolation > Linear).


.

This also can be interesting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbkFn2yaOgg

Just wanted to mention, of course if someone wanted the animation to slow down and speed up etc. one could still use Bézier interpolation, might not look as seamless from its motion, but with your setup it is still seamless regarding the procedural texture. Without this kind of mixing the first and last frame would have different textures and there would be a jump visible in the noise.

Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, this did not give me the effect I was hoping for; as mentioned in my question, it is necessary for the texture to move only on the Z axis, upwards, like fire. With this node set up, the texture appears to move up and down rather than scroll upwards on the z axis in a seamless loop =/

If you copy my setup, which is different from that in the video, it's possible to get the scroll upwards as requested.

Hey Josh, sorry for the confusion; the comment was directed at yourself. I tried the set up in your image, but the result isn't a seamless loop in a single direction: half way through the animation, the texture changes direction from upwards on the Z-axis to downwards on the Z-axis. From beginning to end, this gives it a kind of bouncing effect between the top and bottom of the mesh it's applied to.

It means that there are wrong values in keyframing. Try top texture Z from 0 to -1, and bottom from 1 to 0.

That's done it! Yeah, rather than -1 to 0, the second node had to be 1 to 0. Thank you for your help!
