# How do I map a gradient onto each individual brick in the bricks texture?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to use gradient texture and color ramp with the brick texture. I want each individual brick to have it's own gradient rather than it showing across the whole object as a whole, is this doable in version 2.77?

Comment: You can use methods based on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures to create something like the brick node that can do this, although you need a few more clever tricks to handle the offset and mortar,

Comment: I tried these, it was informative but it's for the faces on the object Geometry. I haven't been able to make it work for the brick texture, unless I'm doing something wrong