# How can I create procedural tiles with uniquely seeded textures for each one? [Updated]

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates

My goal with this experiment was to create a procedurally tiling floor where each tile is unique.

After messing around for a while, this is what I came up with:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

I was really pleased, until I realized I have no idea how to make this tileable/repeatable. I found [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures?rq=1), but those solutions didn't work (or I failed to properly implement them). I tried to find out how to recreate the Brick Texture node from scratch because I think that would probably answer my questions, but [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/brick.html) was really all I could find.

I was even less pleased with my work when I started inserting my marble texture into the material and realized it wasn't going to work. I tweaked some things and this is what I came up with:

[image]

**My end goal is creating a procedural texture where tile shapes are created by a voronoi texture node and each tile has a different "seed".** Is there a way to do this? I imagined using colors values from the voronoi node to provide the value that seeds each marble tile, but I can't figure out how to actually do that.

This is as far as I've been able to get (it doesn't tile and I'm pretty sure each tile's texture is static). Any help and/or feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Updated node tree. Still doesn't do what I want, but at least it's prettier...

[image]

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the help! I spent a few more hours cleaning up the shader and adding a bunch of input sliders. These are the "final" results. The textures, tiles, tile shapes, grout thickness, and seed are fully procedural! The grout is pretty bad, but it's 7AM and I'm going to sleep.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Updated Blender file:**

[image]

Comment: Do you want rectangular tiles, each with a unique texture, or each tile to have a a unique shape? Do you want a region of the overall texture to be seamlessly tileable?

Comment: @RobinBetts I think my two main goals for this practice project are: (1) being able to independently control the size of each tile and scale of the marble, and (2) making each tile's marble texture unique (by somehow seeding each one base on it's color or something?).

Comment: @vklidu Thanks! I retitled the post.

Comment: Independently control the size of each tile? You mean rectangular tiles of different sizes and proportions, all fitting together?

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? I used brick texture (also I can't format well since this is a comment)

Mortar (/grid) size can be adjusted; 

Seed for tiles, you can't control each tiles though; 

Control how many tiles you want; 

Change the color for the marble (with ramp).

Also, are you using an image texture for the tiles? You can use white noise to randomize them

Comment: @RobinBetts For square tiles, no. A 1x1 tile that repeats and is unique each time would be perfect. The image of the marble texture is what I'm trying to achieve, (notice how each tile has a unique pattern that doesn't line up with the one next to it?). But I would also like to create a version where the tiles are created with a voronoi node and each one is unique. I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @CikittaTjok The unique seed for each tile is one of the key things I'm trying to figure out with this practice project. That marble is not an image texture; it's a procedural material that I saw in a tutorial and have been slowly improving. If you download the file, it should be in there (that's what inside the groups in that last screenshot of my node tree).

Comment: @MaxWilliams I kinda figured it out, but then I realized I've deleted some nodes. It might took me some time to make it again XD

Comment: @CikittaTjok Aww, that's the worst. No rush. I appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams Ah I did it! I'll post it on the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: 1/1]

[image: 2/2]

Here's a quick overview! I separated the X & Y, round the values, and multiply the X and Y value. Then, I connect the vector to the White noise to generate random value, connect the randomized value to the vector rotate to rotate each of them individually. I hope this is what you want to achieve :)

Get the file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11keH_2F6pm5L0qdhfqBuNEfbmzChA8Cj/view?usp=sharing

Also did I just recreated the “Poliigon Uber mapping”

Comment: Okay. Let me try to implement this into my shader. I'm using a procedural node group, not an image, so I'm not sure how to incorporate that at first glance. I'll report back shortly.

Comment: Why are there two Separate XYZ nodes? Don't you only need the one?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm not sure, I've tried to use both of them but it doesn't work really well. 
Also connect the vector socket to your node group, if it has a vector socket somewhere and mix the brick texture with the node group result

Comment: This works! OMG, it works! You're a wizard! And it was soooo much simpler than what I had. Wow. Thank you. *And*, it also works if you replace all that math with a voronoi node (which is the second goal I had). Now I just need to figure out how to "find edges" of the voronoi node to make the grout for that version.

Comment: @MaxWilliams ^^

Comment: Instead of the math nodes, you can simply plug a voronoi texture node and set the randomness to 0. Plug the position output into the white noise node to get the "random-per-tile" value. Tweak the voronoi scale to adjust the size of the tiles

Comment: @Gorgious oops, I think I ever heard it somewhere.. oh the CGMatter tutorial

Comment: I think the way you showed is more efficient computation-wise so it's nice to remember this setup if you have trouble rendering your material :)

Comment: @Gorgious I actually did try that, but it doesn't work because the voronoi node doesn't tile from the same origin point. I couldn't figure out how to make that happen (adding 0.5 didn't work). If you know how to resolve that, I'd be happy to know because that could make this shader really simple and allow me to create a slider for the voronoi's "randomness" to change the shape of each tile.

Comment: @CikittaTjok, there was one thing I had to add. You need to divide by 2 between the scale value and the brick texture node's scale because a value of 1 creates a 2x2 grid.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes! I forgot to edit the image, but I believe the file does the thing.. Or maybe I also forgot to update the file and only saved it on my laptop??

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the file until after I copied the nodes from your screenshots (mostly to practice going through the motions). I ended up spending a couple hours refining it and getting it to work with a voronoi node. The final shader is extremely slow, but it works!

Answer (score 6):

I wonder how much computational difference there actually is,between using the Voronoi node for tiling, and doing the maths yourself, especially after you've introduced a couple of Noise nodes to do your randomness for you.. ?

Anyway, you certainly get lot out for not much in, in the way of nodes, with this kind of tree..

[image]

(I've made a group of it, here) .. You get UV-per-Cell, by subtracting the Position output from the texture-space, which lets you tile any texture you like into each cell:

[image]

You get 3 random numbers (a color) per cell, which you can use to randomise any of the cell's attributes (here, used to randomly rotate a texture, per cell):

[image]

And from the parallel Voronoi in the tree, you can get the distance to the cell's edges, which you can use to make a grouting mask, as here, or you can map ranges of it to other ranges to bevel tile edges:

[image]

And you can use the Randomness setting in the Voronoi nodes to take you from square tiles..

[image]

.. to Voronoi tiles, without any further adjustment.

[image]

[image]

(Just the group.. the other trees are a bit of a rushed mess :) )

Comment: Just a little question (REALLY unrelated). Does turning of anti-aliasing for the UI will make the blender run a bit smoother?

Comment: @Cikitta Tjok Hmmm! I'm not sure! I kind of doubt that viewport antialiasing is that much work for the GPU, and any stalling in Blender  e.g. with modifying heavy meshes would be CPU? Wild guess, though....

Comment: First, this is amazing. Thank you. It's similar to what I had going on (several hours of work after getting help from @CikittaTjok) but this answer really helped me understand why all that worked. I didn't know you could label node point connectors (I don't know what they're called). I do have one question though: How can I get the bevel to work with a curves node (for softer edges)? I tried messing around with it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @RobinBetts JK, I figured it out. I've been using the "Height" input, not the "Normal" input on the bump node. Heh...

Comment: It's very like yours..(I guess, it can, as commented, be done more economically, but with more nodes) To manipulate  bevels with a RGB curve node.. something like.. 1. map the edge-distance range of interest to 0-1, with a map range node, to make it easier to handle in the curve-node,use the C curve, and remap/multiply on the way out if necessary.. it depends.. give it a try, and if stuck, post a new question. Just read yours.. Cool!

Comment: @RobinBetts I definitely assume everything I'm doing can be done with about 90% fewer nodes :P After playing around with it a bit more, using the Normal input instead of the Height input doesn't actually worked the way I hoped it would for the smooth tile edges. I shall post a new question. Thanks!