How do I make multi-mesh tileable textures?

Hi,
I am trying to make parts for a dynamically sized panel. The panel consists of corner, side and center parts (depicted in the image). All these parts should be tileable, which is where my problem starts. The project requires me to be hand painting the textures, therefore I am working in Substance Painter. I read much about tileable materials and how to unwrap models for them. But I am at a loss on how to transfer my knowledge to this case. Specifically on how to make multi-mesh tileable textures. If it matters for your answer, the blue lines connect sides, that should be seamless.
Just to emphasise: I am not looking for simple tileable textures, I am looking for tileable textures that work for multiple meshes.
If you have any advice, resources, tips or pointers, it would be highly appreciated!

What texture are you looking to paint, what would these panels actually be made of in real life? Wood, stone, fabric, grass, dirt what is it supposed to look like? Those would probably never really tile seamlessly in real life anyway. Painting software often have a seamless painting methods, though probably not two way symmetry. Textures that tile in two directions are probably not gonna look very good and look repeated. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures/26703#26703

The panel should at the end be a single metallic part, that's why I am trying to make it seamless. I agree with the two-directional tile comment of yours. I can work around that I think. Do you know programs that have seamless functions for two different textures? Because I know typical seamless functions for a single textures, but not for multiple and as I have multiple parts (objects) I have multiple textures, that need to be seamless with each other.

GIMP has a seamless texture plugin, it is not in both directions by default, but it might work if you apply it once, rotate the image and then apply it again. Never tested myself. Krita on the other hand has both seamless painting mode, and various painting symmetry axis, maybe those can be setup in a way that would result in two way seamless painting
